# Point for coordinate Google Maps iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

```
GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(48.f, 35.f);
marker.map = mapView;
CGPoint point = [mapView.projection pointForCoordinate:marker.position];
```

Why point has NaN values?

Printing description of point:
(CGPoint) point = (x=NaN, y=NaN)

Comment: hi have tray GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(48.f, 35.f);
marker.map = mapView;
CGPoint point = [mapView.projection pointForCoordinate:marker.position];  to point wrong values
Printing description of point: (CGPoint) point = (x=3111.020020, y=-1354.228271) whay

Answer (score 0):

Because `CLLocationCoordinate2DMake` waits for `float` values and you are sending an `integer` values instead.

you can do the following:

```
float pointA = (float) (arc4random() % 10);
float pointB = (float) (arc4random() % 10);

marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(pointA, pointB);
```